# HashMap v/s Database . Which one is better?

Tags: android

I want to store track_id and playlist name to display playlist name . So please help me what should i use ?

HashMap or database ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need it to be saved after you close the application, you must need something else then a HashMap, because it will be removed from memory. So you might need a database (or some serialisation to file) after all.

You could save it as a database for persistence, and load it into a datastructure for performance when your app runs. It's hard to say without any information, but maybe a HashMap isn't the best 'soft' sollution either. If you're just saving a list, it might not be your best choice.

Comment: What do you mean by "If you need it to be saved after you close the application"?

Comment: Well, if you stop looking at your application for some reason (you get a call, you go to home, etc) it can be closed (or it can be closed deliberately by pressing back, or by calling `finish()`. Anyway, if you want to save the data, you need something that is not a java datastructure, because they get cleared from memory ofcourse. You have to have something you can use to read the information from when you restart (`onCreate()`), but probably also with onPause etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want persistence then use a database, otherwise, a HashMap will be just fine. As the size of data grows, HashMaps will give better performance over the database. However, they will require more memory as the entire "database" will be stored in RAM for the application's lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

The third option would be using a HashMap in your program and storing the HashMap to a XML file for persistence.